# range of array from getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

Tags: google-apps-script

What's a limit of getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

my data is about 1000 records and just 12 columns in google sheet and i make a google script to get all to show them.
when i show just 10 records, it's not show anything but when i show just 8 records, it's ok.

```
window.onload = () => {
      DATA = '<?!= dataShowAll ?>'
      DATA = JSON.parse(DATA)
      DATA.range.shift()
      //console.log(DATA)
          DATA.range.forEach((row,i) =>{
            $("table tbody").append(`<tr id="TR${i}"></tr>`);
          $("#TR" + i).append(`<td style='text-align:center'>${DATA.range[i][0]}</td>`); 
          $("#TR" + i).append(`<td>${DATA.range[i][4]}</td>`);
          $("#TR" + i).append(`<td>${DATA.range[i][8]}</td>`);
          $("#TR" + i).append(`<td>${DATA.range[i][10]}</td>`);
          $("#TR" + i).append(`<td>${DATA.range[i][2]}</td>`);
          $("#TR" + i).append(`<td>${DATA.range[i][3]}</td>`);
```

how can i show all from google sheet

Comment: Perhaps include how you constructed `dataShowAll`.